# Non existent pages to error page htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was trying to write rewrite rule to return 404 on urls with spam parameters.
I used the following rewrite tool to return error 404 with query string `voxter.pdf&gpvoq` and parameters `gpvoq` but its not producing 404 error.

```
RewriteCond %{voxter.pdf&gpvoq} (^|&)parm1=gpvoq [NC]
RewriteRule  (.*)/error-404.php? [R=404,L]
```

Can u please help me what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

`%{voxter.pdf&gpvoq}` isn't an apache variable. That will only match itself as a literal. You need to be using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (voxter.pdf|gpvoq) [NC]
RewriteRule  ^ /error-404.php? [R=404,L]
```

or some similar regex.

Comment: What I want is, 
the urls ending /index.php?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1 should return error 404. What would be the rewrite rule for this?

Comment: @MacBrian change `(voxter.pdf|gpvoq)` to `voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1`

Comment: SO this should be exact rewrite code
RewriteCond %{voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1} (^|&)parm1=gpvoq [NC]
RewriteRule  (.*)/error-404.php? [R=404,L]

right?

Comment: @MacBrian no, that's what you have in your question, which is wrong, look at my answer

Comment: I am using this code but its sending me to server's 404 page not found, not to my custom 404 page. How to do that?